# How to install mysql 5.5.25 on ubuntu 10.04 32 bit?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-10.04

My application requirement of mysql version is more than 5.5.14 . I had installed mysql 5.5.12 successfully but for later version of mysql 5.5.14 , I could not find any thing best to which I can install mysql 5.5.14 or later version simply. Please tell me the simple way to download and install mysql 5.5.14 or any later version to which I can installed in my ubuntu 10.04 environment .

Please help me out.

Thanks

Nitesh Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Try [MySQL Sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/). You can use it to install from MySQL binary distributions, and install multiple versions side by side.

Comment: I don`t want to use third party tool , I want to install it manually.

Comment: Build it from source or use the binaries then?